# Configure xvfb for Vivid (15.04) as a service using systemd

Tags: services, systemd, xvfb

Vivid switched from upstart to systemd.   I used to have xfvb configured to run as a service under updstart.   That has now broken.

Under upstart, I had */etc/init/xvfb.conf*:

```
description     "Xvfb X Server"
start on (net-device-up
    and local-filesystems
    and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]
exec /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24
```

and I could start it with `sudo service xvfb start`

Under 15.04, I now get this message when I try to use service to start xvfb:

> Failed to start xvfb.service: Unit xvfb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

What is the new way to configure xvfb to run as a service with systemd?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/319040/ .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under systemd you create */etc/systemd/system/xvfb.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=X Virtual Frame Buffer Service
After=network.target

[Service] 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then run

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/xvfb.service
```

At which point

```
sudo service xvfb start
```

will start it:

```
$ ps -elfwww | grep -i Xvfb
4 S root      7807     1  2  80   0 - 51102 poll_s 16:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24
```

and

```
sudo service xvfb stop
```

will kill it

Comment: You could also point out what `sudo systemctl status xvfb.service` will show.  Also note that you could templatize on the display name and have `xvfb@:99.service` instead.

Comment: Your answer here http://superuser.com/a/912648/183672 gives the complete example without the hardcoded :99 that allows multiple screens to be started as a service.

Comment: You could also add `Restart=always` and `RestartSec=3` under [Service] to make Xvfb restart in case it went down for some reason.

Comment: How do I configure it with a file

Comment: @AkshayHazari `/etc/systemd/system/xvfb.service` is a configuration file.